# Password check using a hashed password

Tags: c#, winforms, cryptography

I had a problem, how can I solve the problem. When I try to check the password from the database, something does not work. The hash password is stored in the database.

**In a separate file, there is a password hashing class:**

```
public static string ComputeHash(string plainText, byte[] salt)
{
    int minSaltLength = 4, maxSaltLength = 16;
    byte[] SaltBytes = null;
    if (salt != null)
    {
        SaltBytes = salt;
    }
    else
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int SaltLength = r.Next(minSaltLength, maxSaltLength);
        SaltBytes = new byte[SaltLength];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(SaltBytes);
        rng.Dispose();
    }
    byte[] plainData = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    byte[] plainDataWithSalt = new byte[plainData.Length + SaltBytes.Length];
    for (int x = 0; x < plainData.Length; x++)
    {
        plainDataWithSalt[x] = plainData[x];
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < SaltBytes.Length; n++)
    {
        plainDataWithSalt[plainData.Length + n] = SaltBytes[n];
    }
    byte[] hashValue = null;
    SHA512Managed sha = new SHA512Managed();
    hashValue = sha.ComputeHash(plainDataWithSalt);
    sha.Dispose();
    byte[] result = new byte[hashValue.Length + SaltBytes.Length];
    for (int x = 0; x < hashValue.Length; x++)
    {
        result[x] = hashValue[x];
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < SaltBytes.Length; n++)
    {
        result[hashValue.Length + n] = SaltBytes[n];
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
}

public static bool Confirm(string plainText, string hashValue)
{
    byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue);
    int hashSize = 64;
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[hashBytes.Length - hashSize];
    for (int x = 0; x < saltBytes.Length; x++)
    {
        saltBytes[x] = hashBytes[hashSize + x];
    }
    string newHash = ComputeHash(plainText, saltBytes);
    return (hashValue == newHash);
}
```

**This class, I work with a database (stored procedures are stored in it):**

```
public Boolean CheckLoginTeacher(string login, string password)
{
    bool check = false;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string sql = "BooleanTeachers";
    try
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection)
        {
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@login",
            Value = login
        };
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
        sqlParameter = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@password",
            Value = password
        };
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlDataReader.Read()) //here it shows false, then closes the connection
        {
            if (EncryptonDecrypt.Confirm(login, sqlDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString()) && EncryptonDecrypt.Confirm(password, sqlDataReader.GetValue(1).ToString()))
            {
                check = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    return check;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `something does not work` is a vague and useless problem description

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial time finding passwords by brute force. Also much more complicated code than required, more code == less security.

Comment: To complete @zaph 's answer see [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/86735)

Comment: I certainly understand you, but I am not a professional in this. I'm still just a beginner, I will continue to study ... The main thing for me is to solve the problem, where the class with the database returns false in the while loop. All rows are affected, including in the database, but only why returns false ...

Comment: @ЮрийКуликовский Does sqlDataReader.Read() returns something at least once? I suppose that "BooleanTeachers" is yours stored procedure ant it probably return nothig, that is why there is nothing to read.